# Include OpenX ad in a jquery-ui dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, openx

I'm loading some content into a jquery-ui dialog via .ajax.  That's all working fine but now I've been given an OpenX ad to embed into the dialog & can't figure out how to do it.  I know all the script is stripped when coming in via ajax, & I know how to use $.getScript to load .js files for use in the dialog, but the OpenX ad script I've got uses document.write so I think it's expecting to be embedded inline into the desired position on the page.
I've tried appending the escaped script string into the div on ajax success of the main content as below, but this results in the page being redirected to a page with just the ad on it. 
Attempt shown below:

```
$("#" + idHelpPage).find(".adScript").append("<script type='text/javascript'>var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://d1.openx.org/ajs.php':'http://d1.openx.org/ajs.php');var m3_r = ... etc etc
```

I'm ok with jquery but not great with javascript, would really appreciate any help!  Also if you want to see any other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly this question was asked quite some time ago; however, the openX ajs.php file returns a document.write() function.  If you use jQuery's $(document).ready() class method, it will overwrite your current page.

document.write() will only correctly execute (without overwriting your current page) if it is called during the page load procedure.

There's two ways to overcome this obstacle, and that would entail using AJAX (if your openX server is on the same URL domain as your website, or if you have server side scripting such as PHP, ASP, etc) or JSONP (if your openX server is on a different domain).

You'll have to setup a server side script with PHP, ASP, etc to have your jQuery call using AJAX/JSONP and have that server script load in the URL and return the contents of the document.write() function that the ajs.php file returns.

Comment: Thanks Steve. We moved on from that requirement in the end, the dialog wasn't right for the job, so that simplified things.